# Normalizer not found in PHP 5.3.8 and NOT xampp

Tags: php, internationalization

The only help i can find is about XAMPP installations, but i'm running a fresh root server with Plesk and.. classical LAMP and PHP 5.3.8 - everyone is telling me that Normalizer class must be available in PHP 5.3+, but it's obviously not available in my server..

what is missing, what i have to do that the class is there and running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless PHP was compiled with the `--enable-intl` flag, the Normalizer will not be available. Check using `phpinfo()`. If it's not enabled, you can either recompile PHP, adding that flag, or try the PECL installation.

See http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

If the PHP installation was provided by the OS, perhaps you can use its package manager to add the intl extension as well. With root privileges, just run something like this:

```
$ apt-get install php5-intl
```

Comment: wohoo thanks a lot, exactly what i was looking for :) just one little detail -> the package is named "php5-intl", as written in the intl.installation.php and it worked for me, i just made the apt-get, restarted apache and voilà, intl loaded in phpinfo()

Comment: worked for me same error but in php7.3, so `sudo apt-get install php7.3-intl`